# JTable - Access properties that does not belongs to the specified table

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, jtable

Suppose, I've two tables with following column:

```
#__table1 - id, col1, col2
#__table2 - id, col3, col4
```

I've created JTable class in ***tables*** folder of my component:

```
class ComponentNameTableTable1 extends JTable
{
    function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__table1', 'id', $db);
    }
}
```

In the store method of JTable, I need to access `col3` & `col4`

```
public function store($updateNulls = false)
{
     $col1 = $this->col1; // This is happening
     $col2 = $this->col2; // This is not happening
     $col3 = $this->col3; // This is not happening
     $col4 = $this->col4; // This is not happening
     return parent::store($updateNulls);
}
```

Please note that, I've passed the data from my Model to JTable as follows:

```
public function save($data)
{
    // $data here is an array of containing following value:
    // $data = array('col1' => 'somevalue1', 'col2' => 'somevalue2', 'col3' => 'somevalue3', 'col4' => 'somevalue4');

    // It is then passed to the JTable with following:

    $table = $this->getTable();
    $key   = $table->getKeyName();

    // Get Primary Key Value
    $pk = (!empty($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : (int) $this->getState($this->getName() . '.id'));

    $isNew = true;

    try
    {
        if ($pk > 0)
        {
            $table->load($pk);
            $isNew = false;
        }

        // Bind the data.
        $table->bind($data);

        // Check the data.
        if (!$table->check())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Store the data.
        if (!$table->store())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Clean the cache.
        $this->cleanCache();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException('There was an error while saving data');
    }

    $this->setState($this->getName() . '.id', $table->$key);
    $this->setState($this->getName() . '.new', $isNew);

    return true;
}
```

**My Research**

> It seems that, JTable execute some function which further filters $data and removes keys which are not present in #__table1. If anyone can atleast get me to that table then, I can override it further. I tried to look at bind() method. But it doesn't seems to be filtering that $data as I tried printing the out of $data before bind() get's executed in JTable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you should be using multiple JTable instances in your model when you have multiple tables.

Take a look at these models in the CMS they might give you some direction for how to set up your model.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_installer/models/manage.php

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_contenthistory/models/compare.php